# Union of all hyperplanes in projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I recently read the paper "Compactification of a Drinfeld Period Domain over a Finite Field" by Pink and Schieder. ([link to the paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.4796))

I am confused about two statements appearing in this paper:

(1) removing all proper $\mathbb{F}_q$-rational linear subspaces from $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}_q}^{r-1}$ (line 1~3 on p.202);

(2) $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}_q}^{r-1}\setminus\{ \text{union of all} \ \mathbb{F}_q\text{-rational hyperplanes} \}$ (the first paragraph under Theorem 1.10, p.205).

About the first statement, I cannot understand what a $\mathbb{F}_q$-rational linear subspace is. Since $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}_q}^{r-1}$ is not a vector space, it cannot have "linear subspace", right? So, what is the definition of a $\mathbb{F}_q$-rational linear subspace?

As for the second one, I think that $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}_q}^{r-1}\setminus\{ \text{union of all} \ \mathbb{F}_q\text{-rational hyperplanes} \}=\varnothing$. The definition of a $\mathbb{F}_q$-rational hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}_q}^{r-1}$ shall be the zero locus of a non-constant homogeneous polynomial $f\in \mathbb{F}_q[X_1,\cdots,X_r]$. However, every point in $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}_q}^{r-1}$ must lie on some $\mathbb{F}_q$-rational hyperplane. For example, let $[a_1:\cdots :a_r]\in \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}_q}^{r-1}$. If there exits $i\in \{ 1,2,\cdots,r \}$ such that $a_i=0$, then $[a_1:\cdots :a_r]\in \{ X_i=0 \}$; otherwise, $[a_1:\cdots :a_r]\in \{ a_2X_1-a_1X_2=0 \}$.

It seems that I have misunderstood something, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: In the paper, the scheme you ask about is explicitly defined as the affine scheme of the subring of the field of rational functions generated by all polynomials and all inverses of linear forms. For example, this subring does not contain $\frac1f$ if $f$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $>1$.

Comment: It also does not contain $\frac1{1+\phi}$ for a nonzero linear form $\phi$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A proper $\Bbb F_p$-rational linear subspace is a closed subscheme of the form $\Bbb P^a_{\Bbb F_p}\subset \Bbb P^n_{\Bbb F_p}$ with $a<n$ cut out by linear equations with coefficients in $\Bbb F_p$. They exactly correspond to nonzero proper linear subspaces of $\Bbb F_p^{n+1}$, and it is common to refer to such subschemes as linear, like we sometimes refer to copies of $\Bbb P^1$ as "lines".
2. It should be remembered that a $\Bbb F_p$-rational hyperplane is cut out by a single linear polynomial with coefficients in $\Bbb F_p$, which immediately implies that every closed point on such a hyperplane may be represented as $[a_0:\cdots:a_n]$ with all $a_i\in\Bbb F_p$. On the other hand, not all points in $\Bbb P^n_{\Bbb F_p}$ are of the form $[a_0:\cdots:a_n]$ for $a_i\in \Bbb F_p$. No nonclosed point is of this form, and every non-$\Bbb F_p$-rational point fails to be of this form as well. For instance, consider $\Bbb P^1_{\Bbb F_3}$ and let $i$ be a root of $x^2+1=0$ over $\Bbb F_3$. Then $(x^2+y^2)\subset \Bbb F_3[x,y]$ defines the point $[\pm i:1]$ which is not contained in any $\Bbb F_p$-rational hyperplane (if it were, then the set $\{1,\pm i\}$ would be linearly dependent over $\Bbb F_3$, contradicting the fact that $\Bbb F_3 \subset \Bbb F_3[i]$ is a field extension of degree two with $1,i$ as a basis for $\Bbb F_3[i]$ as a $\Bbb F_3$-vector space).

Comment: So the key point is: $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}_q}^n$ is the projective space over $\bar{\mathbb{F}_q}$; that is, $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}_q}^n=\bar{\mathbb{F}_q}^{n+1}/\sim$. Do I get the point?

Comment: That interpretation is not correct - you're missing all the non-closed points, and you need to glue together non-rational points in each Galois orbit. What is true is that the scheme $\Bbb P^n_{\Bbb F_p}$ has lots of points that aren't $\Bbb F_p$-rational points.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. The definition of the projective space is $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}_q}^n=\text{Proj} \ \mathbb{F}_q[X_0,\cdots,X_n]$, say by Hartshorne's book. The notational confusion is: $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}_q}^n\neq \mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{F_q})$, where $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{F_q})$ by convention is $\bar{\mathbb{F}_q}^{n+1}/\sim$.

Comment: Yes, that's one way to put it. ($\Bbb P^n(\Bbb F_q)$ is $\Bbb F_q^{n+1}/\sim$, though, no taking algebraic closures here.)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I am confused with this problem for a week.